# Javascript object for freshman

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Im quite new to javascript (freshman) and we were given this

```
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
// method is a string that contains the name of a method on the object
// invoke this method
// nothing needs to be returned
```

and I tried this

```
const obj = {
'name': function(){
  this.name = method;
}
}
obj = object;
obj.name();
```

I tried testing it and it failed. It says the obj is undefined. How and where do i declare the object that has been passed as parameter? Please help im stuck for a few hours. Google can't help, or maybe i searched for a wrong one. Thank you

Comment: You are redefining a constant variable.

Comment: And you said that `method` is a string yet you are trying to call it as if it's a `function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the assignment before answering

```js
function invokeMethod(object, method) {
    // method is a string that contains the name of a method on the object
    // invoke this method
    // nothing needs to be returned

    // The assignment ask you to call (invoke) the method inside of `object`
    // The function can be retrieved by using `object[method]`
    // Then, you can call them as you wish, like so:
    object[method](); // This will invoke the method inside of `object`
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What i don't get is how do i create an object inside the function that refers to the 'object' parameter.

Comment: @watdouexpect66 The `object` is an argument of the function, you do not need to create them. Maybe the platform you use will pass an `object` into the first argument

Comment: Test success. thank you kind sir and sorry for bothering you with stupid question ;d

Answer (score 0):

> "the object that has been passed as parameter"

The `object` parameter *has not yet been passed*, what you see in the function is just a name of the parameter. You have to pass the object yourself when you call the function (just like when calling any other function, e.g. `Math.sin(1.234)`). Parameters are positional, outside of the function, the name of the parameter doesn't matter (the names don't have to match). So you just create an object, give it any name (let's say it's `obj`), and call:

```
invokeMethod(obj, ...);
```

Inside the function the name `object` will be bound to (refer to) `obj`, the thing you passed in. It's essentially an alias for the duration of the function (that is, they both refer to the same object).

You wrote:

```
    const obj = {
        'name': function(){
             this.name = method;
        }
    }
```

You don't have to do these shenanigans. Just declare the object normally:

```
    const obj = {
        sayHello: function() {
             console.log('Hi!');
        }
    }
```

In JavaScript, objects are kind of like dictionaries, so every property on them is already stored as a string key. You can invoke the sayHello function like this:

```
obj.sayHello();
```

or like this (not used as often, but it works).

```
obj['sayHello']();
```

> Aside: For example, if you had
>
> ```
> const point = {
>     x: 1, 
>     y: 5
> }
> ```
>
> you could access the value of x by doing `point.x` or by doing
> `point['x']`

Your assignment wants *you* to pass this object and the name of the function to call to the `invokeMethod` function. Again, you have to call it yourself; they want you to invoke the function indirectly by calling `invokeMethod`:

```
invokeMethod(obj, 'sayHello');   // internally, this should call sayHello on obj
```

Once you do that the function will execute, with the `object` parameter bound to `obj`, and the `method` parameter bound to `"sayHello"`. All that remains now is to put the pieces together and fill in the body of the `invokeMethod` function.

Comment: Ohh that makes sense. But on the test, I don't have to call the function bcause if i do, on the npm test it says 'test suiet failed to run', that's why im looking how to pass the object and method parameters inside the function.

Comment: @watdouexpect66 - Oh, there's a test suite? Then most likely there is a test somewhere in there that calls the `invokeMethod` function, probably with some predefined parameters (meaning the test itself creates the object, with some methods on it, and then passes it to the function). When you run the tests via `npm test`, it will execute all those tests (and report if any of them fail). If there's a test suite, than all you need to do is implement the "insides" of the `invokeMethod` function (like the other answer explained), and the test will tell you if you did it correctly.

Comment: @watdouexpect66 - Try finding and opening the file that contains that test, it's likely just a couple of lines of code. You may not understand everything in there, but you'll probably be able to get the gist of what's going on. It's good to get comfortable with looking at the tests, as in real life projects, tests also serve as a sort of documentation, providing examples of what the code under test is for, and how it should behave.

Comment: @watdouexpect66 - BTW, you can fiddle with the test code - change the object there, see what happens (but maybe make a copy of the project first if you're not supposed to modify that). Another thing you can do is experiment in the browser console - hit `F12` (or possibly `Ctrl+Shift+I`) while in the browser (like, right here), it will open developer tools on the side; find the "Console" tab - it's like a little interactive environment that will let you experiment with JavaScript (e.g., try typing 2 + 2 `[Enter]`). You can define objects and functions there and try different things.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I found the invokemethod on the test and all i have to do is follow that example and understand it. This might take a while but, i know it will help. Again, thank you!

Comment: @watdouexpect66 - great! Here's some more info on that. There's probably some setup code around the actual test code, but don't focus on that, it's not really important. I'm guessing what the test is doing is passing in an object that has on it a method that can "remember" if it was called - probably by just setting some variable to true. Then it calls your implementation of `invokeMethod`, and after it's done, it asserts (checks) if that variable was set (indicating that the method was called from within your implementation).